# SQL auto incremental with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, database

I am new to SQL and have tried googling an answer to this but with no luck.

I have the following tables (Simplified):

```
Table1: Transaction
Columns: idTransaction, fkWorker

Table2: Worker
Columns: idWorker (Primary Key, Unique), FirstName, Wage

[fkWorker is linked to idWorker]
```

I want to be able to group more than 1 worker under the same transaction but keep each worker on his own row.

```
E.g.:
[TRANSACTION TABLE]
[IDTRANSACTION][FKWORKER]

|1            ||Worker3 |

|1            ||Worker4 |

|2            ||Worker3 |

|2            ||Worker4 |

|2            ||Worker1 |

|3            ||Worker1 |
```

Is it possible to do this with Auto Incremental but so it doesn't add to the transaction ID until all workers for a particular project have been added to the table? I've explored the option of adding multiple columns for the worker foreign keys eg. fkWorker1, fkWorker2, fkWorker3 etc. however it becomes to tedious with a large range of workers.

Thank you in advance,

Maxim

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding your question. No, but you can incorporate the rollback logic into your insert stored proc or query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible to make use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on the `idTransaction` of the `Transaction` table to achieve the result you want.

The longer answer is that it is possible, it can be done, but the SQL to make that work will be awkward.

The more straightforward approach is to "split" your current `Transaction` table into two tables: `Transaction` and `TransactionWorker`.

Your current table is really the `TransactionWorker` table.  A row in this table represents the relationship between a `Worker` and a `Transaction`.  A `Transaction` may be associated with more than one `Worker`, and an `Worker` may be associated with more than one `Transaction`.

A row in the new `Transaction` table represents exactly one entity. You could use an AUTO_INCREMENT id to assign unique ids to rows in this table.

For that `TransactionWorker` table we often choose a name that somehow signals that it is a relationship table. A row in this table is associated with, or is related to, exactly one `Transaction`, and exactly one `Worker`.

---

```
TABLE: Transaction
       idTransaction  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

TABLE: TransactionWorker
       fkTransaction  INT NOT NULL
       fkWorker       INT NOT NULL

TABLE: Worker
       idWorker       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

---

(In some cases, we can find a different name for the relationship table, for example `Member` or `Membership` on a relationship between `Person` and `Group`.

You can insert a row to the `Transaction` table and allow the `id` column to be generated by the `AUTO_INCREMENT` modifier.

After a row is inserted to the `Transaction` table, you can retrieve the last generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` value using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function (in the same database session).

You can then use that retrieved value in subsequent inserts to the `TransactionWorker` table.

That's the normative pattern for solving this type of problem.

Comment: I think this will work. Thank you very much, especially for the detailed explanation! Cheers, Maxim.

Answer (score 1):

You need three tables not two.  Your transaction table should have the key `TransactionId` along with

1. The `Transactions` table should have `TransactionId` along with information about the transaction (say when and where).
2. The `Workers` table has the information in your `Worker` table.
3. The `TransactionUsers` table is a "join" table.  It has one row for each user in each transaction.  Because all tables should have a primary key, this would have at least three columns:  `TransactionUserId`, `TransactionId`, and `UserId`.

All the primary keys would be auto-incremented.

You would assign the transaction along with the user id in `TransactionUsers`.